# How to use secret key of env file in main.dart when deploying flutter web with flutter actions?

Tags: flutter, github, github-actions, workflow

I deployed flutter web page with `github actions`.

I created workflow.yml in `.github/workflows/workflow.yml`.

```
name: gh-pages

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      - uses: bluefireteam/flutter-gh-pages@v7
        with:
          baseHref: /onldocc_admin/
```

But the problem is that It deploys web site based on repository of github.

I can't ignore .env file. If so, deployment fails.

So I've found many sources and people say to use `secret actions`.

- Github > Settings > Secrets and variables > Actions
  I set `Repository Secrets` as below.

[image]

And mostly people elaborate how to use this key in workflow like below.

```
name: gh-pages

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      - uses: bluefireteam/flutter-gh-pages@v7
        with:
          baseHref: /onldocc_admin/
      - name: Create.env
        shell: bash
        env:
          SUPABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_URL }}
          SUPABASE_ANONKEY: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_ANONKEY }}
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo SUPABASE_URL=${{ secrets.SUPABASE_URL }} > .env
          echo SUPABASE_ANONKEY=${{ secrets.SUPABASE_ANONKEY }} > .env
          cat .env
```

But my questions is I have to use these secret keys in `main.dart` in flutter project.

```
    final supabaseUrlDebug = dotenv.env["SUPABASE_URL"];
    final supabaseAnonKeyDebug = dotenv.env["SUPABASE_ANONKEY"];

    await Supabase.initialize(
      url: supabaseUrlDebug!,
      anonKey: supabaseAnonKeyDebug!,
    );
```

And I need to replace `dotenv.env["SUPABASE_URL"]` to something else, maybe fetching from secret keys from secret repository.

But I can't find this way anywhere!!

If I upload env file, this is too critical on security issue.

Probably there should be any way to solve this..

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use env.json file instead, and while running the application with `flutter run` use the flag `--dart-define-from-file=env.json`

In your case: 
replace your .env file with

```
- touch env.json
- echo '{
  "SUPABASE_ANONKEY" : "${{ secrets.SUPABASE_URL }}",
  "SUPABASE_URL" : "${{ secrets.SUPABASE_ANONKEY }}"
}' > env.json
```

`env.json` will look something like

```
{
  "SUPABASE_ANONKEY" : "<YOUR_SUPABASE_ANONKEY>",
  "SUPABASE_URL" : "<SUPABASE_URL>"
}
```

In code use 
`String.fromEnvironment('SUPABASE_ANONKEY')` 
`String.fromEnvironment('SUPABASE_URL')`

finally, add this to run the application.

`flutter run --dart-define-from-file=env.json`

Comment: `flutter run --dart-define-from-file=env.json` means this works in debug, isn't it? I will deploy this flutter web and need to fetch code from env. when deploying app, I don't use `flutter run`.

Comment: we are talking about maintaining an instance when we talk about environment files, if you are using a Firebase hosting platform you can use flutter build web with the same tag so I don't see any problem there, 

If you think I didn't understand you question, please ask in detail.